# create nested hashmap using lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, hashmap

I want to create three layer `HashMap` using lambda expressions from an input `ArrayList` in Java. The three layers are year, month and week, and here is my code for first two layers. However, in the second layer I am getting an error (first layer works fine).

```
public HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Integer,AbcDetails>>> createHashMapOfTimePeriod(List<AbcDetails> abcDetails){

    Map<Integer,List<AbcDetails>>result1=abcDetails.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbcDetails::getYear));
    Map<Integer,Map<Integer,AbcDetails>>reult2=result1.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> (e.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbcDetails::getWeek)))));

    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with nested `Collector`s:

```
Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Map<Integer,AbcDetails>>> groups = 
  abcDetails.stream ()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy (AbcDetails::getYear,
                                        Collectors.groupingBy (AbcDetails::getMonth,
                                                               Collectors.toMap (AbcDetails::getWeek, Function.identity()))));
```

Note that if there may be multiple `AbcDetails` instances having the same year, month and week, the inner `Map` will have multiple values for the same key, so the above code will fail. One way to resolve such a problem is to change your output to:

```
Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Map<Integer,List<AbcDetails>>>> groups = 
  abcDetails.stream ()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy (AbcDetails::getYear,
                                        Collectors.groupingBy (AbcDetails::getMonth,
                                                               Collectors.groupingBy (AbcDetails::getWeek))));
```

Comment: but in second  and third layer data is repeating only year is unique is that works here?

Comment: @shridhar The only issue may be with the inner most map. If there are multiple objects having the same year, month and week, you would have a duplicate key in the inner most map and must decide how to resolve it. You can change the structure to `Map<Integer,Map<Integer,Map<Integer,List<AbcDetails>>>>` to account for such duplicate keys.